# How to get rid off Token error : Malformed auth code

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I am trying to use google auth with passport.js in my web App
everything works as expected in development. But when I host my application on cyclic
it show google consent prompt but as soon as I click any email.
it show Token Error : Malformed auth code

Below is the exact error details

```
TokenError: Malformed auth code.
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (/var/task/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:373:12)
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (/var/task/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:420:16)
    at /var/task/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:177:45
    at /var/task/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:191:18
    at passBackControl (/var/task/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:132:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:157:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

applink https://cloudy-newt-fashion.cyclic.app

github code link https://github.com/atulchourasiya/QuickNote

Below is the code

```
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
        {
            clientID: process.env.CLIENT,
            clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
            callbackURL: process.env.CALLBACK_URL,
            proxy:true,
            passReqToCallback: true
        },
        async function (request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            try {
                let existingUser = await User.findOne({ oauthId: profile.id });
                if (!existingUser) {
                    const newUser = await User.create({
                        oauthId: profile.id,
                        name: profile.displayName,
                        email: profile.emails[0].value,
                        imageLink: profile.photos[0].value
                    });
                    return done(null, newUser);
                }
                done(null, existingUser);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    )
);
```

```
router.get(
    '/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', {
        scope: ['email', 'profile'],
        session: false,
    })
);

router.get(
    '/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google', {
        session: false,
        failureRedirect: '/failed',
    }),
    function (req, res) {
        try {
            const token = signToken(req);
            res
                .cookie('jwt_auth', token, {
                    maxAge: 11 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
                    httpOnly: true,
                    sameSite: true,
                    secure: true
                })
                .redirect(process.env.CLIENT_URL);
        } catch (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    }
);
```

How can I make it work

Comment: You ever fix this?

Comment: @JimithyPicker yes i have changed the hosting platform from cyclic {free hosting platform} to render {free cloud hosting} and it fix the issue

Comment: they actually had the wrong url encoding on cyclic, so they updated it and its all fixed now!